# Difference between `tasks.named('test')` and `test`

Tags: gradle, groovy

I noticed that https://start.spring.io now uses

```
tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

When it used to be

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I was wondering why the change? The second one seems cleaner even on the IDE.

These are both groovy Gradle no Kotlin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This change has been made to declare tasks lazily, see this Gradle page describing the "Configure avoidance" principles : https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/task_configuration_avoidance.html

Especialy [this part](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/task_configuration_avoidance.html#sec:task_configuration_avoidance_pitfalls) which explains the difference between your two examples ( `someTask` is `test` in your case):

> Beware of the hidden eager task realization. There are many ways that a task can be configured eagerly. For example, configuring a task using the task name and a DSL block will cause the task to immediately be created when using the Groovy DSL

> ```
> // Given a task lazily created with
> tasks.register("someTask")
>
> // Some time later, the task is configured using a DSL block
> someTask {
>      // This causes the task to be created and this configuration to be executed immediately
> }
> ```

> Instead use the named() method to acquire a reference to the task and configure it:

> ```
> tasks.named("someTask") {
>
> }
> ```

( related commit Spring initializr project : https://github.com/spring-io/initializr/commit/27fc9d40672496c93742f562b13544d9a27cd484 )

Comment: And when using Kotlin DSL, you could actually do `tasks.test { ... }`, because Kotlin DSL came after task-configuration avoidance API, so leverages it in the accessors, while the Groovy syntax pre-dates task-configuration avoidance and thus uses the eager logic for backwards compatibility.

Comment: @Vampire thanks for this precision, it's indeed said in the section I mentioned  ( "when using the Groovy DSL")  but  I missed this point